# Is it possible to prevent perforce submit without filename?

Tags: submit, perforce

My usual way to submit a file is:

```
p4 submit –d “some description” filename
```

I could do:

```
p4 submit
```

and use the editor, but I always have many files open, so that method is inconvenient

Several times, I have mistakenly typed

```
p4 submit –d "some description"
```

(forgot the filename)

This submitted dozens of open files to production, with unintended consequences.

Time to panic and spend the afternoon doing damage control.

I would like to prevent `p4 -d` when the filename is not specified.

Comment: One fairly simple technique: when you open files, and don't intend to submit them, run 'p4 change' and put those files in a separate numbered changelist. 'p4 submit -d', without a filename, is only going to submit files opened in the default changelist, so the files in your numbered changelist will not be submitted.

Comment: The Perforce administrator could block submits like that using a Perforce broker, but it's a harder problem in user space. I personally have mostly gone back to submitting without -d for this reason.

Comment: In userspace you could write a wrapper that checks the arguments and either forwards the call to the real "p4" or denies the submission (in case you didn't give the arguments you wanted to give)

Comment: I *never* submit directly from the default changelist.  I always run `p4 change` to put files in a new changelist first, edit the description, double-check that the changelist looks correct (usually this involves going through peer code review), and then use `p4 submit -c CLN`.

Comment: Do you submit directly to the production branch? Maybe it would be safer to create a developer branch and only merge it with production when you are sure everything is fine?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux you can define function in your `.bashrs` file that validates number of arguments and won't let you submit if you miss4th parameter.

```
function p4()
{
    # validate what parameters are passed and if they are correct
    # pass them to /opt/perforce/p4 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pitseeker
I created a Perl wrapper "p4s" which checks the arguments and forwards the call to the real "p4 submit".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_merged';
die "Description and file is required!\n" if @ARGV < 2;
my ($description, @files) = @ARGV;
if ( -f $description ) {
    die "It looks like you forgot the description before the filenames";
}
my $cmd;
my %summary;
print `date`;
for my $file (@files) {
    if ( ! -f $file ) {
        $summary{$file} = "File $file not found!";
        next;
    }
    my $pwd = `pwd`;
    chomp $pwd;

    # print p4 filelog to screen
    print `ls -l $file`;
    $cmd = "p4 filelog $file | head -n 2";
    $cmd = "p4 fstat -T 'headRev' $file";
    print $cmd . "\n";
    my $filelog = `$cmd`;
    print "$filelog" . "\n";

    $cmd = "p4 diff -sa $file";
    my ($merged, $status) = Capture::Tiny::capture_merged {system($cmd)};
    if ( ! $merged ) {
        $summary{$file} = "Skipped since the local file does not differ from p4";
        next;
    }

    # p4 submit
    $cmd = "p4 submit -r -d \"$description\" $file";
    print $cmd . "\n";
    ($merged, $status) = Capture::Tiny::capture_merged {system($cmd)};
    chomp $merged;
    print $merged . "\n";
    if ( $merged =~ /No files to submit from the default changelist/ ) {
        $summary{$file} = "$merged (You may need to 'p4 add' or 'p4 edit' this file)";
        next;
    }
    $summary{$file} = "Success";
}
if ( scalar @files > 0 ) {
    print "\nSummary:\n";
    for my $file (@files) {
        printf "%s    %s\n", $file, $summary{$file};
    }
}
```